# Inner directive is executed first - should be second

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I've got custom directive that has other custom directive in it.
Problem is that first is executed link func from inner directive not outer one. Why?
In outer directive I've got calulation that are crucial for inner directive.
Priority didn't help.

Here is code sample:

```
App.directive('ifSearchSelect', ['$system',function ($system) {
    return {
        restrict: "E",
        replace: true,
        scope: {
            ngModel: "=",
            kolumna: "="
        },
        require:"ngModel",
        priority:100,
        link: function (scope, element, attrs, ctrl) {
            console.log('Not first but I expected it to be');
            //more funcs
        },
        templateUrl: "template/if-form-pola/select.html"
    };
}])
.run(["$templateCache", function ($templateCache) {
    $templateCache.put("template/if-form-pola/select.html",
        "<div>" +
        "<if-input-select ng-model=\"model.ngModel.wartosc\" kolumna=\"::model.kolumna\" dane=\"::model.wartosci\"></if-input-select>" +
        "</div>"
    );
}])

.directive('ifInputSelect', ['$system',function ($system) {
    return {
        restrict: "E",
        replace: true,
        scope: {
            ngModel: "=",
            kolumna: "="
        },
        require:"ngModel",
        priority:50,
        link: function (scope, element, attrs, ctrl) {
            console.log('First supposed to be second');
            //more funcs
        },
        templateUrl: "template/if-input-pola/select.html"
    };
}])
.run(["$templateCache", function ($templateCache) {
    $templateCache.put("template/if-input-pola/select.html",
        "<div>" +
        "Input directive" +
        "</div>"
    );
}])
```

Template:`<if-search-select ng-model="data" kolumna="kolumna"></if-search-select>`

Answer (score 2):

I found solution `pre` in `link` function - here's source http://www.undefinednull.com/2014/07/07/practical-guide-to-prelink-postlink-and-controller-methods-of-angular-directives/

Changed first directive

```
App.directive('ifSearchSelect', ['$system',function ($system) {
    return {
        restrict: "E",
        replace: true,
        scope: {
            ngModel: "=",
            kolumna: "="
        },
        require:"ngModel",
        link: {
            pre: function (scope, element, attrs, ctrl) {
                console.log("Now it's first");
                //more funcs
            },
        }
        templateUrl: "template/if-form-pola/select.html"
    };
}])
```